# proftpd ssh key-based authentication not working

Tags: sftp, proftpd

I've setup a new proftpd server with mod_sftp for SSH support, that I'm able to login to when I use a password. But when I try to use my SSH key, I'm unable to connect.

Here's the full proftpd.conf file:

```
[root@myers log]# cat /usr/etc/proftpd.conf
ServerName                      "Develop CENTS"
ServerType                      standalone
DefaultServer                   on

Port                            2215

UseIPv6                         off

# Umask 022 is a good standard umask to prevent new dirs and files
# from being group and world writable.
Umask                           022

MaxInstances                    15

User                            nobody
Group                           nobody

DefaultRoot ~

AllowOverwrite          on

# Bar use of SITE CHMOD by default
<Limit SITE_CHMOD>
  DenyAll
</Limit>

<IfModule mod_auth_pam.c>
    AuthPAM off
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_sftp.c>
SFTPEngine on
SFTPHostKey /usr/etc/proftpd/rsa_key
SFTPHostKey /usr/etc/proftpd/dsa_key
Port 2216
SFTPAuthMethods publickey      
MaxLoginAttempts 4
SFTPCompression delayed

        <VirtualHost www.mydomain.com>
        SFTPAuthorizedUserKeys file:/home/mydomain.com/.ssh/authorized_keys
        DefaultRoot ~
        </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Here's a line I see in /var/log/messages regardless of the authentication method used:

```
Mar 19 10:41:51 myers proftpd[29675]: myhost.com - unable to create namebind for 'www.mydomain.com' to IPAddress#21: No such file or directory
```

Other than that, the only thing appearing in the log file when I attempt to connect with a SSH key, is that the client does reach the server and a SSH2 session is opened, but the very next line indicates the SSH2 session is closed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your configuration, it looks like you'd like a normal FTP server on port 2215, and the SFTP server on port 2216.  In order to do this, you would need the `mod_sftp` configuration in its own `<VirtualHost>` section.  As your configuration stands, both `Port` directives appear in the same "vhost" context, and thus ProFTPD, when parsing the configuration, may not do what you expect.  I would recommend using something like:

```
# ... previous config ...
<IfModule mod_auth_pam.c>
    AuthPAM off
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_sftp.c>
  # Here we give mod_sftp its own explicit vhost, and put all of
  # of the mod_sftp configuration within that <VirtualHost> section.
  <VirtualHost www.mydomain.com>
    Port 2216

    SFTPEngine on
    SFTPHostKey /usr/etc/proftpd/rsa_key
    SFTPHostKey /usr/etc/proftpd/dsa_key
    SFTPAuthMethods publickey      
    MaxLoginAttempts 4
    SFTPCompression delayed
    SFTPAuthorizedUserKeys file:/home/mydomain.com/.ssh/authorized_keys
    DefaultRoot ~
  </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

```
Mar 19 10:41:51 myers proftpd[29675]: myhost.com - unable to create namebind for 'www.mydomain.com' to IPAddress#21: No such file or directory
```

It's just a cosmetic warning. As I understood you are using proftpd-1.3.5.

> As part of the final work on 1.3.5, I started adding some of the
>   foundation for supporting the HOST command (RFC 7151), which will give
>   FTP true name-based virtual hosting support.  That added code is what
>   is complaining (erroneouly) here. I have fixed up that code, which was
>   erroneously logging that NOTICE level log message, in the master
>   branch on GitHub.  I'll also be updating the
>   1.3.5 branch so that that message is not logged so noisily, for the next maint release (which should be quite soon now).

You can find more at - http://sourceforge.net/p/proftp/mailman/proftp-user/thread/alpine.DEB.2.00.1503301702090.3566%40familiar.castaglia.org/#msg33678099